# How do I create curved bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

In my ongoing project, I need a curved bottom navigation bar. I have tried with [curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar) package. The result I got that's matched 80% of my requirements. The problem I have facing I can't make the **curved position transparent**.

[This is the picture what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEoHq.png)

[This is the picture that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs5QS.png)

Here I've attached two pictures, First picture is what I tried myself I indicate the curved position that I need to make **transparent** and want to see the bottom list view like the second attached picture. Can anyone help me to reach to requirements.

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _page = 0;
  final GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: _bottomNavigationKey,
          index: 0,
          height: 60.0,
          items: <Widget>[
            bottomItem(
                title: "Wish List", index: 0, icon: Icons.favorite_border),
            bottomItem(title: "Home", index: 1, icon: Icons.home),
            bottomItem(title: "My Cart", index: 2, icon: Icons.shopping_cart),
          ],
          color: Colors.black,
          buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _page = index;
            });
          },
          letIndexChange: (index) => true,
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                height: 150,
                color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length],
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }

  Widget bottomItem(
      {required int index, required String title, required IconData icon}) {
    if (index == _page) {
      return Icon(
        icon,
        size: 26,
        color: Colors.black,
      );
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(
              icon,
              size: 22,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            Text(
              title,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make these two changes to your code:

- Change the background of your `CurvedNavigationBar`

```
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
```

- Add this to Your `Scaffold`

```
extendBody: true,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Does `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` fit your usecase?

Answer (score 0):

I have used curved navigation bar. You can make background transparent but there is no option to change curved angles and space between that animation area. You can try fluid_bottom_nav_bar package.